# How to AUTOMATICALLY DELETE mysql records after 2 years

Tags: mysql

So basically I have a table called `acc_rec_pay_old` which stores the deleted data, the table has its own date so how can I delete all records from `acc_rec_pay_old` after 2 years `AUTOMATICALLY`?

Comment: Write a script and put it on crontab

Comment: use the [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Comment: btw can i use cron job or crontab on windows?

Comment: No. Use Event Scheduler instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a cronjob that runs every day that executes the following query:

```
DELETE FROM acc_rec_pay_old WHERE DATE_ADD(date_field, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) = CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: won't that delete newer rows too? (apply it to the current date instead: current_date - 2 years > date_field)

Comment: a date_field from this morning + 2 years will be greater than today

Comment: @davek I totally agree. This wont be a good thing to find out after you apply this answer to existing DB

Comment: That's why you should always run DELETE-queries as SELECTs first. ;)

Comment: Okay i try this one, its really confusing its my first time to use cron job or scheduled scripts

Comment: It didn't work DELETE FROM acc_rec_pay_old WHERE DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) = CURRENT_DATE;
i try to run this as a test on a single row but it didn't work my date format on my table is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: What's the data type of the date column?

Comment: @Sherlock the data type is date

Comment: And the value is set to 2013-01-19?

Comment: No the value is set to 2017-1-2.

Comment: Oh damn i'm so sorry i ddnt change my system time. Thank you for your effort! Really works fine. Sorry again @Sherlock

Answer (score 0):

Write a script in whatever language your comfortable with, create a config file which reads your table name and duration of records to be kept.

Run  this via crontab

Comment: btw can i use cron job or crontab on windows?